# PHPUnit command-line. Configuring --bootstrap

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Sorry for the basic nature of this question but I've tried figuring this out through phpunit docs and online searching but can't piece it together.

I have a number of php classes that I would like to test against via a phpunit cli interface script (windows box) but I'm stuck on a very basic thing.

my test subjects are, e.g., c:\src\classes and test files are here, c:\src\tests

I can run individually by doing the following:

```
$> phpunit --bootstrap c:\src\classes\<name of class subject> c:\src\tests\<name of test file>
```

what I want to be able to is:

```
$> phpunit --bootstrap <something that registers multiple class subjects> c:\src\tests
```

so it would run against all tests in the c:\src\tests directory.

I've found references to the phpunit.xml that would be read prior to each phunit execution which I assume is where I could provide information about where the classes are for the tests, but all references that I've found to this has been unhelpful and have sent me down a couple of rat holes. Could someone point me to documentation that shows this configuration in plain black and white?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you should pass to `--bootstrap` is the path of a PHP script that registers an autoloader that is responsible for loading (only) your classes.

Such an autoloader can be created using a tool like [phpab](http://phpab.net/). [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) also generates an autoloader for you when you use it to manage the dependencies of your project.